# \ref{fig:foo} outputs Figure 1

Tags: chemstyle

Since I'm using the [`chemstyle`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemstyle) package by Joseph Wright a reference to a figure, or scheme (a float environment defined by the package) is always printed as:

> Figure XY

or

> Scheme YZ

Normally one would write someting like

```
Cooking bacon (see figure \ref{fig:Foo bar}) and eggs.
```

And get an output like

> Cooking bacon (see figure XY) and eggs.

Now, with the `chemstyle` package, this renders to:

> Cooking bacon (see figure Figure XY) and eggs.

How can I get back to the normal behaviour of `\ref`?

If you see this Joseph, think about implementing an option to switch the behaviour of this as some people may like the automatic output, but others, as me, don't.

---

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Foo figure}
    \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:foo} shows a Foo.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't test now but you could try with `\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle}`.

Comment: @campa It worked for me in the MWE, so you might want to write up an answer.

Comment: BTW: You probably want to write `Figure~\ref{fig:foo}` with a tie `~` before `\ref` to avoid a line break between "Figure" and the number. Of course `varioref` or `cleveref` make this easier for you because you just type `\ref` and the prefix pops up automatically. That is why I really like this feature, maybe you should give it a try one day.

Comment: Yes, this works just fine! I didn't see this in the documentation, maybe it should be updated. Thanks @campa :)

Comment: @Sam It is on page 3 of the chemstyle documentation.

Comment: @samcarter Yeah I now saw it, but without knowing the `varioref` package the info on page 3 are quite indescriptive as one does not really know what it does. Whatever, campa pointed out the correct option and it works just fine.

Comment: @samcarter Well, yes and no. It's not `varioref` _per se_, it's the following declaration of `\labelformat`, which is indeed not documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `chemstyle` has (lines 425-434)

```
\ifcst@varioref
  \RequirePackage{varioref}
  \labelformat{figure}{\figurename~#1}
  \labelformat{table}{\tablename~#1}
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \labelformat{scheme}{\schemename~#1}%
    }%
  }
\fi
```

By default it loads `varioref` (which isn't the problem) and then changes `\labelformat`, which is a macro provided by `varioref` whose purpose is precisely to control the output of `\ref`. At this point I think you have three options:

**1)** You stop `chemstyle from loading`varioref` with the corresponding option

```
\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle}
```

**2)** You "undo" what `chemstyle` did

```
\labelformat{figure}{#1}
\labelformat{table}{#1}
```

**3)** You enjoy having `varioref` at your disposal and use `\ref{fig:foo}` (or `\Ref{fig:foo}` at the beginning of a sentence) instead of writing `Figure~\ref{fig:foo}` explicitly.